Difference between using [[maybe_unused]] and omitting parameter names
I'm trying to suppress compiler warnings for unused function parameters. I know of two methods:

Using [[maybe_unused]] in C++17 or later:

void foo([[maybe_unused]] int x) {
    // x is unused
}


Omitting the parameter name:

void foo(int /*x*/) {
    // parameter is unused
}

Both approaches work, but I'm curious about the differences between them. Specifically:

Is there any behavioral difference between these two?
Which method is preferable?

Any insight would be appreciated!

I omit the parameter name where I can, but use [[maybe_unused]] if there is a #ifndef NDEBUG block that might use the name, when the file is built that way.

It is probably a matter of personal taste, but I usually prefer [[maybe_unused]] because it's more explicit.

With [[maybe_unused]] you will have smaller diff if at some point you decide to use the parameter, but it's less portable.

if you want to ignore a parameter or local variables, you can also use
(void)foo; in the body.

Best thing I heard is that the "maybe" is not there for show, it's a hint to guide usage

@Raildex Which I think is the worst possible approach. It is just tool satisfaction (using a "C" style cast) and does not convey any intent. With [[maybe_unused]] a developer really shows intent.

@PepijnKramer I disagree. There is no other reason to write (void)x than to silence unused variable warning, so it does convey a meaning. The difference would be that one of these solutions is exposed in the interface and the other is hidden in the implementation. Whether that is good thing or not would be opinion-based.
